# Print doesnt work in webview of android and iOS

Tags: google-cloud-print

I am using the Google Cloud print to in my web application to print the documents.
When i run the app in the web browser it works fine..

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/cloudprint/client/cpgadget.js">
</script>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
alert('Loaded the page');
var gadget = new cloudprint.Gadget();
alert('Loaded the gadget');
gadget.setPrintButton(
cloudprint.Gadget.createDefaultPrintButton("print_button_container"));
gadget.setPrintDocument("url", "Test Page",     
"http://www.google.com/landing/cloudprint/testpage.pdf");
}
</script>
```

But when i run the app web app using a webView in android (UI Webview in iOS) .. the print doesn't work. It successfully loads the printer list ... I am able to select the printers and proceed to final print page. Afterwards when i click print , nothing happens.

Please share your thoughts on the same

Comment: hey have you solved this problem. I just started work on a similar app and facing exactly the same problem

Comment: No... I didn't get a solution for this issue till now.

Comment: I have the same problem in ios. I solved the problem by making use of google sign in sdk and calling api of google cloud print